# Symfony2: KnpDoctrineBehaviours default locale based on current locale

Tags: symfony

I have got 2 locales (de, en) for my project.
Not every entity is translated in both languages.
So if my current locale is "de" and there are entites not translated into german, the english version of these entities should be shown.
The other way round if the current locale is "en" and there are entities not translated into English, the German version of these entities should be shown.

How could I achieve this?

I'm using KnpDoctrineBehaviours for my translations. The doTranslate() method first looks for translations based on the given locale.
If no translation has been found it looks for translations with the default locale.

```
protected function doTranslate($locale = null, $fallbackToDefault = true)
{
    if (null === $locale) {
        $locale = $this->getCurrentLocale();
    }

    $translation = $this->findTranslationByLocale($locale);
    if ($translation and !$translation->isEmpty()) {
        return $translation;
    }

    if ($fallbackToDefault && $defaultTranslation = $this->findTranslationByLocale($this->getDefaultLocale(), false)) {
        return $defaultTranslation;
    }

    $class       = self::getTranslationEntityClass();
    $translation = new $class();
    $translation->setLocale($locale);

    $this->getNewTranslations()->set((string)$translation->getLocale(), $translation);
    $translation->setTranslatable($this);

    return $translation;
}
```

Right now I have just overridden the TranslatableTrait as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#override).

Is there any better way than overriding the complete doTranslate method of the TranslatableTrait?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the usefullness of the fallback locale because it is used to retrieve a translation for a determined string when it doesn't exist for the current language (for that is usually used the EN language, so anyone can understand). For that you should use only one locale for the fallback, because you have to be sure it exist.

Comment: Okay. I think I have not asked my question properly. Fallback locale might be the wrong word. The default locale based on the current locale might be a better word choice, because KNP first looks for translation based on the current locale and if no translation has been found it will look for a translation based on the default locale. But my problem still isn't solved. I will update my question a little bit.